# Swapping Scenes with a buttons generated via loops.(JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

I'am generating `Buttons` with the following code:

```
public static void addSitesButton() {

        Button buttons[] = new Button[CsvScanner.numberOfLines + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < CsvScanner.numberOfLines && i< 19; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new Button();
            addPages(i, buttons[i]);
        }
    }
```

the `addPages()` method has

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
        button.setTextFill(Color.CRIMSON);
         buttonClicked = (((Button) e.getSource()).getText());
    });
```

with that i only get the number of the button i created.

With that code i generate the needed `Scene` and `Grid`.

```
public static void createGrids() {

    GridPane gridArray[] = new GridPane[buttonCounter];
    Scene sceneArray[] = new Scene[buttonCounter];
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonCounter; i++) {
        gridArray[i] = new GridPane();
        sceneArray[i] = new Scene(gridArray[i]);
    }
}
```

I need to change the `Scene` with the created `Buttons`.
For example: First Button have to change to the first Scene in the array.
I have no idea at all how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If buttonClicked give an int value, you can do.

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    button.setTextFill(Color.CRIMSON);
    int buttonClicked = Integer.parse((((Button) e.getSource()).getText()));
    stage.setScene(sceneArray[buttonClicked]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your button text does not contain int value you can record their array indices as `AccessibleText`

```
for (int i = 0; i < CsvScanner.numberOfLines && i< 19; i++) {
       buttons[i] = new Button();
       buttons[i].setAccessibleText(i+"");
       addPages(i, buttons[i]);
}
```

And then

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    button.setTextFill(Color.CRIMSON);
    int buttonClicked = Integer.parse((((Button) e.getSource()).getAccessibleText()));
    stage.setScene(sceneArray[buttonClicked]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can record a value related to the button in [`userData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData-java.lang.Object-) when the button is created and access that saved value whenever you have a reference to the button.

For example, record the user data at the creation of a button:

```
buttons[i] = new Button();
buttons[i].setUserData(i);
```

And then, when you need to access it, retrieve the user data which you had saved:

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    int buttonIndex = (int) button.getUserData();
    // do whatever you need to with button index...
});
```

If you need to associate multiple pieces of data with a given node, then you can use the [`node.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getProperties--) API, but, for your question, usage of the node `userData` property is probably all you need.

> I need to change the Scene with the created Buttons. For example: First Button have to change to the first Scene in the array. I have no idea at all how to accomplish this.

Assuming you have already initialized your scene array and user data for your buttons, you should just be able to do:

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    int index = (int) button.getUserData();
    stage.setScene(sceneArray[index]);
});
```